# How to set cookie to secure in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

In my Rails application, I want to have my cookies secured but it's not working.

I currently force SSL in my production.rb file but it's not securing the cookies even though it should from what I read.

I'm on Rails 5+, and  don't have the session_store.rb file that I see in the different threads. I tried making it and my cookie is still not secured.

I tried adding this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_application_session', secure: true, httponly: true
```

but, then I don't see the "second" set-cookie when I use `curl` in my console. Because of that, when I login on my website, it redirects me to the index without logging in.

I have this in my production.rb:

```
 config.force_ssl = true
 config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl }
 config.to_prepare { Devise::RegistrationsController.force_ssl }
 config.to_prepare { Devise::PasswordsController.force_ssl }
```

How do I fix this on Rails 5+?

Comment: Are you accessing your app over `https://`?

Comment: Yes I am using https to access it which just makes it more strange..

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using the Securityheaders gem : https://github.com/github/secure_headers

Made an initializer with the following content :

```
SecureHeaders::Configuration.default do |config|
    config.cookies = {
        secure: true, # mark all cookies as "Secure"
        httponly: true, # mark all cookies as "HttpOnly"
        samesite: {
            lax: true
        }
    }
    config.hsts = "max-age=#{1.week.to_i}"
    config.x_frame_options = "DENY"
    config.x_content_type_options = "nosniff"
    config.x_xss_protection = "1; mode=block"
    config.x_download_options = "noopen"
    config.x_permitted_cross_domain_policies = "none"
    config.referrer_policy = %w(origin-when-cross-origin strict-origin-when-cross-origin)
    config.csp = SecureHeaders::OPT_OUT
end
```

The rest I just used rails' pre-built csp since it was way too complex for me to do it by hand with the gem.